# cscope doesn't show results in quickfix window

Tags: vim, erlang, cscope

my cscope_maps.vim is

```
if has("cscope")

""""""""""""" Standard cscope/vim boilerplate

" use both cscope and ctag for 'ctrl-]', ':ta', and 'vim -t'
set cscopetag

" check cscope for definition of a symbol before checking ctags: set to 1
" if you want the reverse search order.
set csto=0
set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
" add any cscope database in current directory
if filereadable("cscope.out")
    cs add cscope.out  
" else add the database pointed to by environment variable 
elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
    cs add $CSCOPE_DB
endif

" show msg when any other cscope db added
set cscopeverbose
```

just use [github:cscope_maps.vim](https://github.com/chazy/cscope_maps) and add option `set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-`
my result is alway like [image]
,there is no quickfix window. what's wrong?

Comment: Did you open the `quickfix` window with `:copen`?  The window is not opened automatically.

Comment: I don't know how to reply under comments.to Sato: :copen　really helps. but I remember old version I don't use this copen option. Now I have to type :copen everytime I start Vim? Is

Comment: to romainl:: the search results.  from Sato answer, I know I can use :copen to open quickfix window.But is there someway automatically?